# How can I align the label to the top right at the same time in packs() method of labeling widgets in Python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, alignment

I tried to use that code block to align a label to the top right or bottom left-like-sides, but packs() method doesn't allow two arguments...

See my code:

```
import tkinter
class guigui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main=tkinter.Tk()
        self.label11=tkinter.Label(self.main, text="label text 1")
        self.label2=tkinter.Label(self.main, text="label text 2")
        self.label1.pack(side="right")
        self.label2.pack(side="bottom")
        tkinter.mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    agui=guigui()
```

I wanted to align text 2 to bottom so I tried to do like that:

```
self.label2.pack(side="right")
self.label2.pack(side="bottom")
```

But it didn't work. The second line of that block is executed but the first one is always ignored, and everywhere is written in the`pack()` method allows only the left and right bottom top sides, okay but what am I suppose to do if I want to align label text the cross areas?

Comment: Try `.pack(side="bottom", anchor="e")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error in line 5.

Change this:

```
self.label11
```

to:

```
self.label1
```

Change this:

```
self.label2.pack(side="right")
self.label2.pack(side="bottom")
```

to:

```
self.label1.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)
self.label2.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)
```

Output:

[image]